# C# Socket Send and Receive on Same Machine

Tags: c#, sockets

I am in the process of making a C# socket library that can be accessed in Visual FoxPro. Ideally, the library will contain two functions: ReceiveMessage and SendMessage. On each call, the function is supposed to {open connection -> read/write -> close connection}. I found most of what I am looking for at http://www.csharp-examples.net/socket-send-receive/; however, now I have to test (on the same machine) the modified code before compiling the dll.

I keep getting a "connection actively refused" error. While I have included all of the code below so you can see what it is doing, the issue is almost certainly in the main() at the bottom. It is my limited understanding that I cannot have two connections to the same port, but I am at a loss on how to fix it. Does anybody know sockets who can give me some direction on how to test these functions (I am new to sockets)?

```
namespace Sockets
{
    class Sockets
    {
        private static void Receive(Socket socket, byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, int timeout)
        {
            int startTickCount = Environment.TickCount;
            int received = 0;  // how many bytes is already received
            do
            {
                if (Environment.TickCount > startTickCount + timeout)
                    throw new Exception("Timeout.");
                try
                {
                    received += socket.Receive(buffer, offset + received, size - received, SocketFlags.None);
                }
                catch (SocketException ex)
                {
                    if (ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.WouldBlock ||
                        ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.IOPending ||
                        ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.NoBufferSpaceAvailable)
                    {
                        // socket buffer is probably empty, wait and try again
                        Thread.Sleep(30);
                    }
                    else
                        throw ex;  // any serious error occurr
                }
            } while (received < size);
        }
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        private static void Send(Socket socket, byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, int timeout)
        {
            int startTickCount = Environment.TickCount;
            int sent = 0;  // how many bytes is already sent
            do
            {
                if (Environment.TickCount > startTickCount + timeout)
                    throw new Exception("Timeout.");
                try
                {
                    sent += socket.Send(buffer, offset + sent, size - sent, SocketFlags.None);
                }
                catch (SocketException ex)
                {
                    if (ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.WouldBlock ||
                        ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.IOPending ||
                        ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.NoBufferSpaceAvailable)
                    {
                        // socket buffer is probably full, wait and try again
                        Thread.Sleep(30);
                    }
                    else
                        throw ex;  // any serious error occurr
                }
            } while (sent < size);
        }
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public static string SendMessage(string ipAddress, string port, string message)
        {               
            Socket socket = new TcpClient().Client;
            try
            {
            socket.Connect(ipAddress, Int32.Parse(port));

                Send(socket, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message), 0, message.Length, 10000);
                socket.Close();
                return "Success";
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                socket.Close();
                return e.Message;
            }
        }
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public static string ReceiveMessage(string ipAddress, string port, int bufferSize = 1024)
        {
            Socket socket = new TcpClient().Client;
            try
            {
            socket.Connect(ipAddress, Int32.Parse(port));
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                Receive(socket, buffer, 0, buffer.Length, 10000);
                socket.Close();
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                socket.Close();
                return e.Message;
            }
        }
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Thread(delegate() {var test = Sockets.Sockets.SendMessage("localhost", "60010", "abcdefg");}).Start();
        new Thread(delegate() {Console.WriteLine(Sockets.Sockets.ReceiveMessage("localhost", "60010"));}).Start();
        var waitForEnter = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to have a listener for the connections. I bet when your apps running it isnt listening on 60010,

Comment: @BugFinder Yep, that did it. I would mark your answer as the best solution if it were an answer and not a comment. Since I can't, I'll post the functioning Receive procedure for future coders. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a tilda (~) as the trailing character, here is the functional receive function (old code is commented):

```
public static string ReceiveMessage(string ipAddress, string port, int bufferSize = 1024)
{
    try
    {
        TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(new System.Net.IPAddress(IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress).GetAddressBytes()), Int32.Parse(port));
        serverSocket.Start();
        TcpClient clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();

        NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
        int bytesRead;
        string buffer = "";
        byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[bufferSize];

        while (true)
        {

            bytesRead = networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, bytesFrom.Length);
            string incoming = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom, 0, bytesRead);
            buffer = buffer + incoming;
            while (buffer.Contains("~"))
            {
                string msg = buffer.Substring(0, buffer.IndexOf("~"));
               // buffer = buffer.Remove(0, msg.Length + 3);
                return msg;
            }

        }


        //var socket = new TcpListener(new IPAddress(IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress).GetAddressBytes()), Int32.Parse(port));
        //try
        //{
        //byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        //    Receive(socket, buffer, 0, buffer.Length, 10000);
        //    socket.Close();
        //    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        //}
        //catch (Exception e)
        //{
        //    socket.Close();
        //    return e.Message;
        //}
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return e.Message;
    }
}
```